# how to pass variables from r program to mysql function

Tags: mysql, r

I am new to R Programming and MySQL.  I have a requirement where I need to read the variables from R Programming and need to pass those as inputs to a function in MySQL. 
Can someone please help me in this regard?

```
options(echo=FALSE)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
start.date <- as.Date(args[1])
end.date <- as.Date(args[2])
library(RMySQL)
mydb = dbConnect(mydb,xxxx)
rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb,"SELECT COMPUTE_WEEKS(start.date,end.date) FROM DUAL;")
```

Below is the error I am getting.

rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT COMPUTE_WEEKS(start.date,end.date) FROM DUAL;")
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown table 'start' in field list

Need to understand how to read data from r-program and pass it as arguments to procedures/functions in My-SQL.  Currently using RMysql library.

Regards
Bhanu Pratap M

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the *R variables* called `start.date` and `end.date`, then you can use `paste` to build the query string:

```
query <- paste0("SELECT COMPUTE_WEEKS(", start.date, ", ", end.date, ") FROM DUAL;")
mydb <- dbConnect(mydb, xxxx)
rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first set the value of the dates in consideration as variable. Then, you can easily put them into a *paste0*-statement. See the code below. Moreover, you need to put quotes around dates in MySQL. This is not considred in the answer from Tim Biegeleisen.

```
library(RMySQL)

#Set start and end date
start <- "2016-01-01" 
end   <- "2016-02-01"

un   <- ""  # Set user name
pw   <- ""  # Set pass word
host <- ""   # set host
name <- ""  # data base name

# Conncect to data base
db   <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = un, password = pw, host = host, dbname = name) 

# State your query  
query      <- paste0("SELECT COMPUTE_WEEKS('", start, "', '", end, "') FROM DUAL")

# Send query to data base
send_query <- dbSendQuery(db, query) 

# Unfetch query to get results in data frame
df         <- fetch(send_query, n = -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The above suggested methodology worked.

Comment: @Pratap Thanks for your reply. If my answer was helpful you can accept it as the correct answer. Just hover with your mouse over the check mark left to my answer and click on it. Then you also upvote my answer.